# Pillow's Image open cause core dumped and aborting of python for some webp images

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, python-imaging-library, webp

I have some png images. In the code I first convert them to webp then I try to make thumbnail from webp image, but for some images trying to open webp image cause **core dumped** and termination of python.

For converting images to webp I use this code:

```
original_image = Image.open(path).convert("RGBA")
webp_image = Image.new("RGBA", orig.size)
webp_image.paste(original_image, mask=0)
webp_image.save(webp_path, "WEBP", quality=100)
```

then when I run following code:

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open(webp_path)
```

I get this error:

> python: vp8l.c:619: GetHtreeGroupForPos: Assertion `meta_index < hdr->num_htree_groups_' failed.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

I tried all combination of **Pillow=2.9.0/3.0.0** and **libwebp-dev==0.4.0/0.4.4** but with no success. The host OS that get this error is **Ubuntu 14.04 trusty**.

What can I do about this error? I should report this bug in [libwebp-dev package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libwebp)?

Any suggestion will be very helpful.